# Estimaing the mode from a list of values sampled from a continuous distribution

Tags: python, statistics

I have values sampled from a continuous distribution, for example:

```
import numpy as np
values = np.random.normal(loc=0.4, scale=0.1, 1000)
```

How can I estimate the mode based on those values ?
The mean and median are easy to compute: `np.mean(values)` and `np.median(values)`; but for the mode I don't know how estimate it, since the values are continuous.

Note that using something like `scipy.stats.mode` would not work because I have a finite set of values sampled from the continuous distribution.

Comment: If you have a known, underlying parametric model, life is easy.  Fit your data (using MLE or whatever) and take the mode of the fitted distribution.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a known, underlying parametric model, life is easy.  Fit your data (using MLE or whatever) and take the mode of the fitted distribution.  If  you don't have a good parametric model, life is harder.  There are a number of things I've seen in the literature, but I don't know if any sort of consensus has been reached on this.  When I had to do this (~20 years ago) I used an algorithm I found in Numerical Recipes in C.  I have no idea if that was the best choice or not.